# Passing a file as one string argument to a bash function

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a Bash function that wraps a `java` command for convenience. The command accepts an argument which is actually JSON and can be somewhat large, so I prefer to store it in a multi-line file.

Here is a simplified example.

The Java program `Test` just prints out its last command-line argument as-is, with newlines and indentation as in the JSON file. This works:

```
$ java Test -s test "$(cat test.json)"
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Test"
}
```

Now my Bash function looks like this:

```
jwt() { java Test $@; }
```

When I now call the function with the `cat` "subcommand", the passed argument is broken:

```
$ jwt -s test "$(cat test.json)"
{
```

```
$ jwt -s test "`cat test.json`"
{
```

The same command lines work in *zsh* but I'd like to learn how to do this with *bash*.

---

Another example - instead of `java` I'll just use `echo`.

This works:

```
$ echo "$(cat test.json)"
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Test"
}
```

Bash function:

```
e() { echo $@; }
```

Calling it:

```
$ e "$(cat test.json)"
{ "id": 123, "name": "Test" }
```

Surprisingly, the white-space is compressed into single spaces here. Wondering what the difference to Java is.

Comment: Quote it: `e() { echo "$@"; }`

Comment: @anubhava that puts all command-line arguments into one string, which is not what I want in practice. The second example was a bit too much simplified, but as you can see in the first example, there may be other arguments.

Comment: No `"$@"` doesn't put all arguments in one string as the case with `"$*"`

Comment: If you call `e` with a single argument, there's no difference between `"$@"` and `"$*"`. I don't see how `e "$(cat test.json)"` can produce the output  you claim. Using *either* `$*` or `$@` (unquoted) causes `echo` multiple arguments after word-splitting is applied.

Comment: @anubhava I stand corrected, your solution seems to work. I'll try it tomorrow at work. Thanks.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is really useful for debugging shell scripts. I fed it your functions and got this: [SC2068 - Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"$@"` is a special case, which correctly preserves arguments as intended.

```
$ cat Foo.java
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String arg: args) {
      System.out.println("'"+arg+"'");
    }
  }
}

$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

foo() {
  java Foo "$@"
}

foo arg1 arg2 "arg 3"

$ sh foo.sh
'arg1'
'arg2'
'arg 3'
```